# decode pandas data frame with sklearn

Tags: python, dataframe, sklearn-pandas

I have a data frame with many columns. some of them are string and some other are integer.
I used this code to encode my data frame:

```
le = LabelEncoder()
for col in df.columns:
    df_encoded[col] = df.apply(le.fit_transform)
```

it worked! but when I want to decode it with this code:

```
for col in df.columns:
    df_decoded[col] = df_encoded.apply(le.inverse_transform)
```

I receive this error:

```
ValueError: ('The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()', 'occurred at index MYCOLUMNNAME')
```

Comment: provide complete error message and sample df too

Comment: This is the complete error. I just removed the name of column for not making confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of data differs from column to column, so using `apply` with `fit_transform` won't work here. It will seem to work properly but the `LabelEncoder` will be fitted to the rightmost column at the end of the operation, so when you'll try to apply the `inverse_transform`, the LabelEncoder will replace all the elements in the other columns with the ones it saw in the rightmost column. E.g.:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{'A': 1, 'B': 'p'}, {'A': 1, 'B': 'q'},  {'A': 2, 'B': 'o'},  {'A': 3, 'B': 'p'}])
df
   A  B
0  1  p
1  1  q
2  2  o
3  3  p

df = df.apply(le.fit_transform)
df
   A  B
0  0  1
1  0  2
2  1  0
3  2  1   # Looks fine

df.apply(le.inverse_transform)
   A  B
0  o  p
1  o  q
2  p  o
3  q  p   # Whoops
```

You will see the same result even if you iterate over the columns one by one and perform the `fit_transform` and `inverse_transform`.

You need to fit the encoder to the correct column before inversing:

```
le = LabelEncoder()
df_encoded = pd.DataFrame(columns=df.columns)
df_decoded = pd.DataFrame(columns=df.columns)

for col in df.columns:
    df_encoded[col] = le.fit_transform(df[col])

df_encoded
   A  B
0  0  1
1  0  2
2  1  0
3  2  1

for col in df.columns:
    le = le.fit(df[col])
    df_decoded[col] = le.inverse_transform(df_encoded[col])

df_decoded

   A  B
0  1  p
1  1  q
2  2  o
3  3  p   # Yeay
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It worked! ...another question...What if we have something like this "P,Q'' in one of our cells in column B? I want to encode P and Q separately...I think it is a list inside the cell